# R DEoptim() function: How to select parameters to be opimised?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I wish to estimate parameters for the following Example:

But how can I make DEoptim to only optimise say 2 of the 3 parameters?
- Is there a direct method to do this?

```
rm(list=ls())
t <- seq(0.1,20,length=100)

Hobs <- 20 + 8*exp(-0.05*t)
Hsim <- function(p,t) {p[1] + p[2]*exp(-p[3]*t)}
upper <- c(30,10,1)
lower <- -upper

resFun <- function(p, t, Hobs) {
          r <- Hobs - Hsim(p,t)
          return(t(r)%*%r)
}

DEoptim(resFun, lower, upper, Hobs = Hobs, t = t, 
                      DEoptim.control(NP = 80, itermax = 200, F = 1.2, CR = 0.7, trace =FALSE))
```

I found a workaround cf below. But is there a more elegant way of doing this?

```
rm(list=ls())
t <- seq(0.1,20,length=100)

Hobs <- 20 + 8*exp(-0.05*t)
#Hkorr <- rnorm(100,0,0.2)
Hsim <- function(p,t) {p[1] + p[2]*exp(-p[3]*t)}
upper <- c(20,10,1)
lower <- c(1,1,0.001)
sel = c(0,1,1)
ini = c(20,NA,NA)
# correct upper and lower to selected parameters
upper <- upper[which(sel==1)]
lower <- lower[which(sel==1)]

resFun <- function(par,t,Hobs, sel, ini) {
          p <- rep(NA,3)
          p[which(sel == 0)] <- ini[which(sel==0)]
          p[which(sel == 1)] <- par
          r <- Hobs - Hsim(p,t)
          return(t(r)%*%r)
}
DEoptim(resFun, lower, upper, Hobs = Hobs, t = t, sel = sel, ini = ini,
        DEoptim.control(NP = 80, itermax = 200, F = 1.2, CR = 0.7, trace =FALSE))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `upper` and `lower` parameter value to be equal for whichever parameter you want to hold constant.

```
# Hold the first parameter constant at 20
opt <- DEoptim(resFun, c(20, -10, -1), c(20, 10 ,1), Hobs=Hobs, t=t,
               DEoptim.control(NP=80, itermax=200, F=1.2, CR=0.7))
```

Comment: as a side note: it's a shame that `DEoptim()` doesn't have the option to store e.g. the errors and the methods `confint` + `vcov`

Comment: @TobyElTejedor: what do you mean? Differential evolution does not use a covariance matrix or confidence intervals.

Comment: I know. But it would be nice to have an inbuilt calculation for the parameter uncertainties (sensitivites). e.g. calculating the Jacobian.

Comment: ok. I've written a procedure to numerically calculate a sensitivity matrix under the assumption, that the shape of the objective function is symmetric close to the optimum parameter set.