# R DEoptim() function: How to use smaller initial population number than Npop

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

You'll need the `DEoptim` package for this question:

```
install.packages("DEoptim")
library(DEoptim)
```

From the `help(DEoptim)`

```
Rosenbrock <- function(x){
x1 <- x[1]
x2 <- x[2]
100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2
}

lower <- c(-10,-10)
upper <- -lower

## run DEoptim and set a seed first for replicability
set.seed(1234)
DEoptim(Rosenbrock, lower, upper)
```

Now this works fine: 
However, if I provide an initial population `Npop` with `dim(Npop)[1] < 10*length(lower)`

```
xini <- cbind(runif(10),runif(10))
ran <- abs(lower - upper)
Npop <- apply(xini,2,function(x) x*ran+lower)
DEoptim(Rosenbrock, lower, upper,DEoptim.control(initialpop = Npop))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in DEoptim(Rosenbrock, lower, upper, DEoptim.control(initialpop = Npop)) : 
Initial population is not a matrix with dim. NP x length(upper).
```

How can I do this?

Related to this question: [R DEoptim() function: How to select parameters to be opimised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564844/r-deoptim-function-how-to-select-parameters-to-be-opimised)

where e.g. 1 parameter is not estimated and I do not have to account for it in the 
`DEoptim.control(initialpop)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the workaround I got from the author of `DEoptim()`

```
library(DEoptim)

#From help(DEoptim)

Rosenbrock <- function(x){
          x1 <- x[1]
          x2 <- x[2]
          100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2
}

lower <- c(-10,-10)
upper <- -lower

## run DEoptim and set a seed first for replicability

set.seed(1234)
DEoptim(Rosenbrock, lower, upper)

n <- length(lower) * 10 
# n <- length(lower) * 5 

xini <- cbind(runif(n),runif(n))
ran <- upper - lower
Npop <- as.matrix(apply(xini,2,function(x) x*ran+lower))
DEoptim(Rosenbrock, lower, upper, DEoptim.control(NP=n,initialpop = Npop))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answer above, the apply function doesn't seem to give the correct matrix.  I believe you need to apply by rows (1) and then transpose the matrix.

```
Npop <- t(as.matrix(apply(xini,1,function(x) x*ran+lower)))
```